# How do I programmatically block websites on an ASUS router via iptables?

Tags: router, iptables, asus

I'm running an ASUS RT-AX88U-4168; the router's web admin allows me to configure rules that block all traffic to certain websites. I'm trying to recreate that same ability via the router command line [1].

I can see the existing rules that I've configured via the web interface in the iptables:

```
admin@RT-AX88U-4168:/tmp/home/root# iptables -L  | grep HOST


REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            WEBSTR match url HOST.com  reject-with tcp-reset
```

I *think* I should be able to retrieve the command-line used to create this rule via iptables-save:

```
admin@RT-AX88U-4168:/tmp/home/root# iptables-save | grep HOST
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m webstr--webstr HOST.com  -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

However, if I try to recreate that with another host/site, I get complaints:

```
admin@RT-AX88U-4168:/tmp/home/root# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m webstr--webstr NEWHOST.com  -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
iptables v1.4.12.2: Couldn't load match `webstr--webstr':No such file or directory
```

Other attempts that don't pass the command line:

```
admin@RT-AX88U-4168:/tmp/home/root# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m webstr --webstr NEWHOST.com  -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
iptables v1.4.12.2: unknown option "--webstr"
```

This version successfully passes on the command-line, but does not seem to have any actual effect when attempting to load a page from NEWHOST.com:

```
admin@RT-AX88U-4168:/tmp/home/root# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m webstr --url NEWHOST.com  -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

I'd deeply appreciate any pointers in the right direction!

[1] My goal is to create time-based blocks; if I can add and remove blocks via the CLI, I can have a cron job that periodically updates the blocks.